# how can I proceed when I can't type in the EC2 instance ubuntu

Tags: php, python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

the attached image is my Xshell remote control cli of ubuntu in aws ec2 instance.
while I am setting up the mysql-client, ubuntu required root password with 'underline', however, can't proceed after that.

please help me with to proceed.

this is my ubuntu image
[image]

Comment: What does it mean "I can't type"?

Comment: You type and press enter. it won't show on terminal as you type but it is getting typed.

Answer (score 3):

The password is not displayed, nor is the cursor, when you type.  This is normal.

Comment: Yeah. I'm also expecting this is the case. But I asked OP to clarify what he means by saying "I can't type".